# How to filter Notification Access Screen to my app?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, notification-listener

At the moment I ask for the permission to use the Notification Access (Notification Listener Service) in the following way:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

This does work, but the user has to choose my app from a list of apps.

[image]

To improve the usability, I'd like it to look more like this

[image]

Does anyone know how to filter it properly?

For the usage access settings I use the following Code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Sadly, this does not work for notification access settings.
Error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS dat=package:notificationmanager }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), YOUR_LISTENER_CLASS.class.getName());
Intent notificationAccessSettings = 
    new Intent(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS));

notificationAccessSettings.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_COMPONENT_NAME, componentName.flattenToString());
            
startActivity(notificationAccessSettings);
```

This was only introduced in API Version 30, and I don't know a way (or if it is even possible) for earlier versions.

Comment: yes its working for android R(api level 30). but earlier version.