# Notification access for specific app below from api level 30?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

how to filter the notification access for specific app in android. I find the answer for api [level 30](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300961/14630265) not working for earlier api if any one know please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notifications fail to display in Android Oreo (API 26)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395669/notifications-fail-to-display-in-android-oreo-api-26)

Comment: @VojinPurić not brother, I talk about the notification access permission not about the notification display.